# How to use exec to run bash one liners

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I had used `exec` in the past to run basic `bash` commands and `awk` as well from tcl.

But this time I am running some complex 1 liner to edit a variable name.

```
set v "sccmp_hvt_c35_ff_0.99v_125c.lib"
set corner_name [exec "echo $v | cut -d'.' --complement -f2- | cut -d'_' --complement -f-5 | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'"]
```

This is not working and throwing `error for '[a-z]'` as an invalid command.
Is there any way which can help me running this bash script through tcl?

Comment: What is your desired output? Is it "SCCMP_HVT_C35_FF" ?

Answer (score 2):

The square brackets must be escaped:

```
# wrong
exec echo abc | tr [a-z] [A-Z]

# good
exec echo abc | tr \[a-z\] \[A-Z\]
```

In your case, I would try:

```
set corner_name [exec "echo $v | cut -d'.' --complement -f2- | cut -d'_' --complement -f-5 | tr \[a-z\] \[A-Z\]"]
```

**EDIT**

Moreover, I think that quotation marks are not needed:

```
set corner_name [exec echo $v | cut -d. --complement -f2- | cut -d_ --complement -f-5 | tr \[a-z\] \[A-Z\]]
```

Comment: Tried but it says no such file or directory while executing it.

Comment: Do i also need to escape ' after cut, because it now throws error for cut saying: cut: the delimiter must be a single character

Comment: I think you do not need the `'` characters

Comment: You are right, removing ' helps me getting the desired o/p.
Thanks

Comment: The Tcl equivalent of `'` in Unix shell is `{`…`}`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
set corner_name [string toupper [join [lrange [split [lindex [split $v .] 0] _] 0 3] _]]
puts $corner_name   ;# => SCCMP_HVT_C35_FF
```

which you can also get with

```
string toupper [regexp -inline {^.*?(?:_.*?){3}(?=_)} $v]
```

Comment: Yes, that was the desired output, you did it natively in tcl rather then using shell script. Thanks